# Scanning words in a text file by Golang

Tags: go, text, cpu-word, scanning

I want to split a text file(file.txt) into two separate equal size texts files such as file1.txt and file2.txt. My strategy in the split is to scan words and count them and then write the first half of the words to file1.txt and the rest to file2.txt 
This is the code:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)
func main() {
    WordbyWordScan()
}
func WordbyWordScan() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    count := 0
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        count++
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", count)
}
```

https://godoc.org/bufio#example-Scanner--Words

As far as I can guess scanner.Scan() returns a boolean. After counting the number of words, How I can implement such a code in Golang that states write the first half of words to file1.txt and the rest in file2.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
var s []string 
.
.
.
for scanner.Scan() {// storing or appending file.txt string values to array s.
        s = append(s, scanner.Text())
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    //writing to file1 and file2
    if len(s)%2 == 0 { // if the occurences of words is an even number.
        for i := 0; i <= len(s)/2-1; i++ { // Writing first half of words to file1
            fmt.Fprintln(file1, s[i])

        }

        for j := len(s) / 2; j < len(s); j++ { // Writing second half of words to file2
            fmt.Fprintln(file2, s[j])

        }
    } else { // if the occurences of words is an odd number.
        for i := 0; i <= len(s)/2; i++ { // Writing first part of words to file1
            fmt.Fprintln(file1, s[i])
        }

        for j := len(s)/2 + 1; j < len(s); j++ { // Writing second part of words to file2
            fmt.Fprintln(file2, s[j])

        }
    }
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cut the file in half, then you are halfway there. After counting the words, simply go back and read the file again, writing half to one file an half to the other:

```
file.Seek(0,0)
scanner = bufio.NewScanner(file)
scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
w:=0
for scanner.Scan() {
   var outfile *os.File
   if w<count/2 {
     outfile=file1
   } else {
     outfile=file2
   }
   fmt.Fprintln(outfile,scanner.Text())
   w++
}
```

Above, `file1` and `file2` are the two output files.

If you don't  need to cut the file in half but simply put half of the words in one file and the other half to the other, you can do this in one pass, without counting. Simply switch the file to write to as you're reading from the first:

```
w:=0
for scanner.Scan() {
   var outfile *os.File
   if w%2==0 {
     outfile=file1
   } else {
     outfile=file2
   }
   fmt.Fprintln(outfile,scanner.Text())
   w++
}
```

Comment: Do you have an idea also for splitting the first half of words from the second of half of the words in order? I mean like this sentence: "You can now access all content from the conference on-demand for the next month."

The first half of words: "You can now access all content from the"

The second half of words: "conference on-demand for the next month."

Comment: Counting the words writing the first half to one file and the second half to the second would do this

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    WordbyWordScan()
}
func WordbyWordScan() {
    file, err := os.Open("file.txt.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    file1, err := os.Create("file1.txt.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    file2, err := os.Create("file2.txt.txt")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer file.Close()
    defer file1.Close()
    defer file2.Close()

    file.Seek(0, 0)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)
    w := 0

    for scanner.Scan() {
        var outfile *os.File
        if w%2 == 0 {
            outfile = file1
        } else {
            outfile = file2
        }
        fmt.Fprintln(outfile, scanner.Text())
        w++
    }

    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}
```